# Writing custom expansion in bash, e.g for square brackets []

Tags: bash

Is it possible to write custom expansion hooks in bash, just like what bash does for {a..b}? I  want to implement a capability to expand/manipulate square brackets [content] and the content inside that. I want all the existing scripts/commands to work as-is

Comment: Not without recompiling.

Comment: Why are you trying to clobber the expansion it already performs with that?

Answer (score 1):

No, `bash` does not support this feature.

---

While it's not inconceivable that a version of `bash` *could* be written that allows some sort of custom parsing hooks, `[...]` would be a bad choice since square brackets are already used as a synonym for the `test` command and for regular expression bracket expressions (i.e., `[ab]cd` to match either `acd` or `bcd`). You would be hard pressed to define another use for square brackets alone that don't interfere with these existing uses. (Although it's not impossible, as the obsolete `$[...]` notation for arithmetic  expressions shows.)